# Why is the last character when typing into a text field always selected in my flutter application on ios?

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run my Flutter app on an ios device or ios simulator and I type into any text field the last character as I am typing is showing it as selected. It doesn't replace that character it's just showing it selected visually. I don't want this to happen. This does not happen when running on an Android simulator.

Here is an explanation of the problem. So in the text field if I type "abcd" then the "d" is selected and if I continue typing "abcde" then the "e" is selected. This continues as type. Another thing it only does it for alphabetical characters it doesn't select the last character if i type - or @ or any other similiar character.

What could be causing this, it's so weird because it happens in all the text fields in my application?

Edit: So this appears to be an ios 17 beta bug because i ran this on a simulator with ios 16.4 and it doesn't do it. So i wonder if this is going to be fixed when ios 17 comes out. I don't know whats causing this though. Appears to be all flutter apps I tested it on some large Flutter apps on the appstore and they all do it.

Found some more info of people having same problem
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/128406

```
child: TextField(controller: _controller)
```

Comment: add the code snippet where this issue occurred.

Comment: It's simply a text field controller but it does it on all my text fields even on different pages. Another thing i just noticed it doesn't select the last character if i type - or @ or any other similar character just alphabetical characters is when it happens.

Comment: weird. Try running the app on a physical device or another emulator.

Comment: I did it does it on my physical device and it does it on all the iphone simulators. I ran it on an android simulator and it doesn't do it. It's very strange.

Comment: hmm, strange indeed. Try creating a dummy project and see if it still occurs.

Comment: try to  **autocorrect: false**  TextField property

Comment: So this appears to be only happening on IOS 17 Beta i just ran it on IOS 16.4 and it doesn't do it

Comment: I have the same thing in my Flutter app. Same app on physical device with iOS 15.6.1 does not have this effect. Very strange. My app is build with flutter 3.7.10. Will try the hin with autocorrect from Darshan.

Comment: was it working with autocorrect false ?